# Eclipse headless build doesn't create jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ant, headless

I am starting an eclipse headless build from the cmd through a batch file. It outcome is "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" but in the defined directory is no jar file or project directory. If I execute this directly from the Eclipse IDE GUI I just have to define the Build file, which I also do in the batch file, and it works fine... Does anyone know what I can do that my eclipse headless build starts through the batch file?

Batch file:

```
for /r C:\ProjektNEU\Source\java_extensions %%x in (*build.xml) do (java -jar C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\eclipse-jee-2019-09-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.500.v20190715-1310.jar^ 
-application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner^ 
-Ddata=C:/Users/Administrator/eclipse-workspace^ 
-buildfile %%x^ -DbuildDirectory=C:/Temp^ 
-DbaseLocation=C:/Polarion/polarion)
```

Result in the cmd:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>(java -jar C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\eclipse-jee-2019-09-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.500.v20190715-1310.jar -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -Ddata=C:/Users/Administrator/eclipse-workspace -buildfile C:\ProjektNEU\Source\java_extensions\com.polarion.idl.compoundPropertiesExtension\build.xml -DbuildDirectory=C:/Temp -DbaseLocation=C:/Polarion/polarion )
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration\logback.1.13.0.20190716-1624.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://952.fwk821087498:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://952.fwk821087498:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Buildfile: C:\ProjektNEU\Source\java_extensions\com.polarion.idl.compoundPropertiesExtension\build.xml

plugin_export:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 14 seconds
```

Result in the directory is nothing happened at all.

Start through the Eclipse IDE GUI:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

How can I manage that my build creates the JAR file without the eclipse GUI?

**Edit:**
The Build.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="plugin_export" name="build">
    <target name="plugin_export">
        <pde.exportPlugins destination="C:\Temp" exportSource="false" exportType="directory" plugins="com.polarion.idl.compoundPropertiesExtension" useJARFormat="false"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: What is this build.xml? Is it building an RCP, a Jar, something else? Note that for building an Eclipse RCP the only supported method is using [tag:maven] and [tag:tycho]

Comment: It is building a JAR file, so it should work

Comment: You need to show us the contents of the build.xml

Comment: Updated the Question with the build.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build.xml you have shown is for exporting an Eclipse plug-in and should only be used for plug-ins.

It uses the Eclipse only `pde.exportPlugins` Ant task. This task only **starts** the export running, it requires Eclipse to be kept running for some indefinite time until the export completes. There isn't really a good way to wait for the export to finish when using it in a headless build. It is intended only to be used from the Eclipse GUI.

Note that all Eclipse PDE build processes are now in maintenance mode and as such should not be used in new code. [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) and [tycho](/questions/tagged/tycho) are the recommended ways to build plug-ins and RCPs. This [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) does a good job of covering Tycho.